# Google Ajax Feed API - How to change date format?

Tags: javascript, ajax, api, rss

I am using googles ajax feed api to feed from an RSS. However, i'm just wondering how to change the date format, `"datePublished`" feeds the date as:

```
Sun, 29 Jan 2012 23:37:38 -0800
```

How can I make this:

```
Sun 29 Jan <br /> 23:37
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Convert it into javascript date,

```
var d = new Date('Sun, 29 Jan 2012 23:37:38 -0800');
d.getDay()   // to get day, 0 for Sunday
d.getDate()  // to get Date
d.getMonth()  // to get Month and so on.
```

Refer: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_obj_date.asp